# Google custom search api how to get only the url

Tags: google-custom-search

I use the google custom search api, that work nice, but I need to get only the url. I didn't find how do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into: [Customizing Results Snippets](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/snippets)

Comment: thanks, i have looked this, but i don't found anything who can helped me to do that i want :/

Answer (score 0):

**Although question is too old but i am writing an answer for other people**

yes it is possible

for that you need to add an additional parameter `fields=items(link)` in your `Get` request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/demo/v1?key=YOUR-API-KEY&fields=items(link)
```

not only `url` you can get any kind of field   from google `cse` result

here is the source https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/performance

with all  details

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation points to comment, but the response recommending https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/performance gives the correct result. Also, if one needs specific information of multiple elements, like link and title, add the required elements to the parenthesis.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=GCP_PROJECT_API_KEY&cx=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXX&q=search+for+something&fields=items(title,link)
```

The link I used is a little different than https://www.googleapis.com/demo/v1 because I copied the link from the first 'Try it' button at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox . The 'Try it' button gave an example at https://jsfiddle.net/gtpqzhac/ and I copied the root link and cx value. This configuration happily works!